# New SAT Math Section: Comparing Equation of Line to Graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, functional-equations

This is a math question on a practice test for the New SAT that will come out in March. These questions should not go above the level of precalc. I'm posting a picture of the problem as well because it's a graph related question. I'm unsure about how to go about solving the problem. The equation of the line seems close to point-slope form but it isn't exactly.

Question: If $0<c<1$, which of these could be the graph of 
$y-x=c(x+y)$ in the $xy$-coordinate plane?

[The Graphs for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gli91.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$y-x = c(x+y) \Rightarrow  y = \bigg(\frac{1+c}{1-c}\bigg)x$$

And $d$ is the only graph with a positive gradient.

Comment: I got it thanks, I completely didn't think about solving for y, I was stuck on point-slope form!